# Rails how to run a custom query and return an array of map

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 2 models in my app. Let's say ModelA (id, attributeA1, attributeA2) and ModelB (id, attributeB1, attributeB2). Now I want to run a custom query:

```
select attributeA1, attributeA2, attributeB2 from ModelA inner join ModelB on ModelA.id == ModelB.id
```

The end result is I want to have an array. Each element is a map with these keys :attributeA1, :attributeA2, :attributeB2.

Comment: This question is way to abstract for anyone to bother. If you want answers add actual code representing the models and schema and an example of the existing data and desired output.

Comment: Did you try anything? check ActiveRecords and Arel docs, you can do selects and joins pretty easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is like the following.

```
  connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
  res = connection.exec_query(%Q(
    select attributeA1, attributeA2, attributeB2 
       from ModelA inner join ModelB 
       on ModelA.id == ModelB.id
  ))
```

and then you can iterate the result by `res.rows` and `res.columns`

Answer (score 1):

You can find example in ActiveRecord documentation
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-filtered-data-from-multiple-tables